# Why does PHP shortens a large number when typecasting?

Tags: php

The following example prints `2147483647` instead of `13757966641806459594`

```
$i = '13757966641806459594';
echo (int) $i;
```

Comment: Use a 64-bit system to avoid this problem. (or at least make it much *much* less likely)

Comment: cast to a float and  you should be okay or you gmp_ functions for higher precision math.

Comment: Dear down-voter, please explain why you down-voted. This appears to be a legitimate question with willing people to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2147483647 is the maximum of a 32-bit signed integer. The value of 13757966641806459594 is larger than PHP can handle in this case. You can read more in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) on how to handle the overflow.

Comment: Well you don't need a variable to get this behavior you can have something like this `echo (int) '13757966641806459594';`

Comment: @LoganMurphy very true. Any time you're dealing with an integer, the overflow is possible, edited my answer to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.